# How to handle .rej files in mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I am getting some .rej files while workin with mercurial. Can anyone tell me what are these and how to handle these?

Answer (score 1):

When there are merge conflicts, or an applied patch fails to patch one or more chunks, the .rej files show the rejected chunks.  They represent parts of the merge or patch that failed.  If you've resolved the merge to your satisfaction, they can be deleted.